# Bootstrap row height based on static image height

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

So for each message I want to have the profile picture on the left hand side and then next to it have the username and message. This works but I want the image to always be a square and stay the same size no matter what the screen size is..

So I'm making a row for each message, then making the image 1 column and the message the other 11 columns. How can I make it so each row's height is always at least the height of the image if I want the image to be 40x40 pixels big.

```
 messages.forEach(function(message){
            $chatbox.prepend(
                    "<div class = 'member-message row'>" +
                        "<img src ="+ member_pics[message.creator]+" class= 'profile-img col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1'>"
                        + "<div class = 'col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11'> <b>" +  message.creator + ": </b>" + message.content + "<br/>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>" );
        });
```

[image]

right now it squishes the image to be the height of the row even though i have css that does

```
.profile_img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the img to see what is causing the squishing?

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` to the image.

Comment: @danielrsmith I think it's because the row/div is only as tall as the text so it does that for the image too.

Comment: @Autista_z Didn't change anything, still squished

Comment: @joe I'd check the padding and margins that is being applied to that row/column and image.  You may need to modify that.  It would help if you posted an example that we can look at.

Comment: @danielrsmith realized profile-img was suppose to be the css class but that didnt fix it, now its squishing it vertically - http://imgur.com/s8KJrBH

Comment: try adding !important to your width and height in your profile_img css

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `col-*-1` classes are adding right & left padding to that cell.  Try removing the padding for columns with `profile-img` added to them.